# Ubuntu Pro Image

Tags: 22.04, iso, ubuntu-pro

for a use case I need a pre-hardened (using Ubuntu Pro) ISO-image for an edge device. Is something like this available? I can only find cloud-images or the way of "attaching" the pro license :(

Thanks
Lukas

Comment: What do you mean by "pre-hardened""? What exactly are you trying to do? Please edit the question to add more details.

Comment: Ubuntu Pro is a commercial product sold by Canonical (whom we are not). We are Ubuntu users who volunteer to help other Ubuntu users. We have no additional information about Ubuntu Pro than you do. The best way to get a specific answer about an Ubuntu Pro feature that might meet your enterprise's need is to contact the Sales Department at Canonical (whom we are not).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.